# Tomcat Folder as Classpath?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web-applications

I have a really weird issue with Tomcat that I can't seem to fix. My issue is that it seems that Tomcat sees the Tomcat folder (C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6) as the classpath. This issue comes into effect when I set my JAVA_OPTS to reference my properties file.

```
-Ddoiadmin.properties.file=doiadmin.properties
```

I have the properties file in my classpath (WEB-INF/classes) however when I start Tomcat, I get the error:

```
com.XXXXX.commons.servicecore.ServiceConfigurationException: Could not find main properties file (directly or on classpath): [doiadmin.properties]
```

The only way to get the application to properly start is to put the properties file in the Tomcat folder. This is annoying and not something I want to do in the long run.

I scoured the internet and asked a few people to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks for any help
-Tim

Comment: Did you install using the Windows installer? If so, check the service settings (it should have installed a control panel).  Try with just the ZIP version running from the startup.bat and see if that works.  You may also need to check your system environment variables, there may be something there that's causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was using the windows installer but I tried with the zip and I got the same error. I also added:

    -Ddoiadmin.properties.file=doiadmin.properties

to my System properties to no avail.

Comment: I'm not sure what classes are causing this, but they are in your webapp's jar or classes folder right?  They aren't in the tomcat/classes directory are they?

Comment: I put my project's lib files in tomcats lib folder also. Is that bad?

Comment: Yeah, its going not going to be part of your webapp classpath, but the tomcat 'global' classpath.  Tomcat uses a set of nested classloaders, so that the contents of the Tomcat/lib directory are in the parent classloader and their classpath will be different than classes loaded from within the webapp.

Comment: Thanks for your help Robert. I changed the structure of my JARs (I put them in my WEB-INF/lib folder) and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly I would do this:

In you web.xml have the following:

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>RootPathPropertyName</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>uk.co.foo.project.path</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>

<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>RootPathPropertyValue</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  <env-entry-value>d:/foo/bar</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

In you context set up a PlaceHolderConfigurer as follows:

```
<!-- Properties Configuration -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
     class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="order" value="1"/>
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>file:${uk.co.foo.project.path}/config/foo.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

In your tomcat config you can override the default location with the following in the file /conf/Catalina/localhost/foo.xml:

```
<Context path="foo" >
<Environment name="RootPathPropertyValue" value="c:/foo/bar" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
</Context>
```